# convergence of disjoint subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $\{A_i\},i\in I$, is some partition of $\Bbb N$ such that $|A_i|=\aleph_0=|\Bbb N|,\forall i \in I$ , and all the sets $A_i$ are well ordered, then for a real sequence $\{x_n\}$ it is true that

$x_n\rightarrow x$ if and only if  $ \forall i \in I,x_{n_i}\rightarrow x,n_i \in A_i$

How can we prove this? or there is some reference for this?

Comment: It's not true. If $I$ is a finite set, then it's true, but not for infinite $I$.

Answer (score 0):

Take any partition $A_1, A_2, \dots $ of $\mathbb {N}$ you like with each $A_k$ being infinite. For each $k,$ let $n_k$ be the smallest element in $A_k.$ For $n\in A_k,$ define $x_n$ as follows: $x_{n_k}=k, x_n = 0, n \in A_k\setminus \{n_k\}.$ Then for each $k,$ $x_n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ within $A_k.$ But the range of the full sequence $x_n$ contains $k$ for each $k\in \mathbb {N},$ hence is unbounded, hence can't converge to $0$ (or anything else).